# New HttpClient instance with different interceptors

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

Regarding angular documentation https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

> If you import HttpClientModule multiple times across different modules (for example, in lazy loading modules), each import creates a new copy of the HttpClientModule, which overwrites the interceptors provided in the root module.

How to achieve that? How to have 2 services with http clients with different interceptors? In lazy loading module, it will work of course, because of new injector creation, but what to do for no lazy loaded modules?

Here is an example app - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhijvu.
All the fun is in app.module.ts. In the logs, we can see that clients from both services have the same interceptor chain.

Regards

Comment: In your stackblitz, modules are not lazy loaded. You import both Module1 and Module2 together. The docs specifies a particular behavior for lazy loading, not feature modules.

Comment: Yes.. and the question is `how to do that for feature modules?`. The doc does not specify this behavior for lazy loading but shows it as an example. Actually I understand why this happens, but can't find a solution how to prevent chaining interceptors for not lazy loaded modules.

Comment: What you could do is using a single Interceptor, whithin which a service is injected, and the service will carry a boolean saying what to do (the code inside your previous Interceptor1, or the code within your previous Interceptor2). Could it work ? Can a service carry such a boolean (so you have to know when to switch from one to an other ?)

Comment: It would work, but it is not sound elegant. Target idea is to have few services call different apis witch few interceptors in chain each. I don't want to have `if` statements tree but structural solution.